# Linux bash: how to list every logged in user, but every user should be shown only once?

Tags: bash, unix

At the moment I am trying with the:

`w --no-header`

but it lists the same user twice:

```
myuser tty7
myuser pts/0
```

How to make it to give me back only once?

It should be simply

`myuser`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you filter for just the first column, then sort/uniq, you would use

```
w --no-header | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Put it in a shell function and there you go.

Comment: Thanks this helped. Any idea how to cut the seconds from the command `uptime -s`? So I get this: `2021-03-19 11:03:13` and make it into this: `2021-03-19 11:03`

Comment: That is a new question to which the answer would be `set -- $(uptime -s)`. Now you have the strings in the shell's $1 and $2 and can use `echo $1 ${2%:*}` to remove the shortest string matching `:*` from the right end.